# Insomnia how to upload file and json data

Tags: json, http, testing, request, insomnia

How can I test data like this

```
{
    "slug": "some-slug",
    "poster": "here must be image",
    "translations": {
     "ge": {
            "title": "geo text ",
            "shortDescription": "get text",
            "description": "geo text"
     },
             "en": {
            "title": "en text",
            "shortDescription": "en text",
            "description": "en text"
     }
    }
}
```

plus I have a poster file, where I must upload an image file.
I tried selecting multipart, something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVjbB.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWr9e.png

but it still does not work, Is it possible to send both data in insomnia?